# Object prototye property in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What attributes does the newly created property in  prototye have that it cant be replaced see below::

```
Object.prototype.name="Maizere";
x=new Object();
console.log(x.name)//logs maizere
x.name="Pathak";
```

Instead of replacing the value of property with same name in prototye instead new property is created on object ,so i need to know everythig behind this confusing code

Comment: One property is on the prototype the other is on the instance.

Comment: *Assignment* (writing) always happens on the object itself, not on its prototype chain. If the property does not exist yet on the object, it is created first. Only for *reading* the property is looked up on the prototype(s) if it does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the new object (before setting its name), you have something like this:

```
Object
> prototype
  > name = "Maizerre"
```

So if you get its name, it looks first at its own properties, then at its prototype chain until it finds it.

At the end of the code, you have this:

```
Object
> name = "Pathak"
> prototype
  > name = "Maizerre"
```

Now when you ask for the name, it finds the one that's the property of the object itself, and doesn't go looking along the prototype chain.